# Include a source file in a C program

Tags: c

How can I include foo() function of foo.c in this small program (sorry for my noob question):

In my foo.h file:

```
/* foo.h */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int foo(double largeur);
```

In foo.c:

```
/* foo.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "foo.h"

int foo(double largeur)
{
  printf("foo");
  return 0;
}
```

And in main.c:

```
/* main.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "foo.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("Avant...");
  foo(2);
  printf("Apres...");
  return 0;
}
```

After compiling:

> $ gcc -Wall -o main main.c

I get this error:

> Undefined symbols:   "_foo",
>   referenced from:
>         _main in ccerSyBF.o ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just a note: to ensure the `printf()` calls "work", you shoukd include a '\n' in the text to print: eg `printf("Apres...\n");`. Usually the output strean (`stdout`) is line buffered and only complete lines (with the `\n`) are sent to the output device unless you force them with `fflush(stdout);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to compile `foo.c` also because it is another module. Let me see how they do it in `gcc`:

```
$ gcc -Wall main.c foo.c -o main
```

Comment: @Denis: This will work for now while your program is small. You may want to look into Makefiles once your programs get larger and have more dependencies.

Answer (score 14):

```
$ gcc -Wall -o main main.c foo.c
```

GCC doesn't know to look for `foo.c` if you don't tell it to :)

Answer (score 6):

Creating a program in C requires two steps, compiling and linking. To just run the compiling part, use the `-c` option to `gcc`:

```
 gcc -c main.c
```

This creates an object file, `main.o` (or `main.obj` on Windows). Similarly for `gcc -c foo.c`. You won't get the error message above at this stage. Then you link these two object files together. At this stage, the symbol `foo` is resolved. The reason you got the error message was because the linker couldn't find the symbol, because it was only looking at `main.o` and not `foo.o`. The linker is usually run from `gcc`, so to link your object files and create the final executable file `main`, use

```
 gcc -o main main.o foo.o
```

Comment: `-Wall` turns on the many warnings "about constructions that some users consider questionable, and that are easy to avoid". To get more warnings I often use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wswitch-default -Wcast-align -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wstrict-prototypes -Winline -Wundef -Wnested-externs -Wcast-qual -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -std=c[89]9 -pedantic ...`

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this in your MakeFiles, like this:

```
APP_NAME = Foo
Foo_HEADERS = foo.h
Foo_FILES = main.c foo.c
```

If you're not so much familiar with MakeFiles i suggest you to take a look at [Make Docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/), but this is a simple example, `APP_NAME` sets the name of the compiled executable(in this case is Foo), `Foo_HEADERS` will set the headers used by your application, `Foo_FILES` you will set the source files of your applications, remember to put the `APP_NAME`(in this case Foo) at the beginning of `_HEADERS` and `_FILES`. I suggest you to use MakeFiles because they will organize you application build process and will be better for the end-user.